# Creating PO receipt (Return) throws error "An error occurred while processing the field Vendor Ref. value <> has already been used"

Tags: acumatica

i am using Screen based API and it was working, recently started getting error saying the vendor ref exists on the document.

I noticed that the webservice call is somehow trying to create the document 2 times and on the second time it gets this error.

Following is the code, and i cant figure out what is wrong.

```
         PO302000Content ReturnSchema;    
        ReturnSchema = context.PO302000GetSchema();

         context.PO302000Submit(new Command[] { ReturnSchema.Actions.Insert });
        //HEADER
          AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Document = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
                    {
                        new Value
                        {
                            Value = interfaceStatus.Doc1Type,
                            LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.Type
                        },
                        ReturnSchema.Actions.Insert,
                         new Value
                        {
                            Value = BPCode,
                            LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.Vendor,
                            Commit = true
                        },
                         new Value
                        {
                            Value = BPRefNbr ,
                            LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.VendorRef
                        },
                         new Value
                        {
                            Value = PostDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)PostDate.Value).ToLongDateString() : "",
                            LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.Date
                        },              
                         new Value
                        {
                            Value = Comments,
                            LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.NoteText
                        },
                        new Value
                        {
                            Value = "TEST VALUE",
                            LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.VendorRef
                        }
                    };
        context.PO302000Submit(Document);

    //LINE
         AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Docline = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
                                    {
                                     ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                                    new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = line.ItemID, 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.InventoryID 
                                    },

                                     new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = OutletCode, 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.Warehouse 
                                    },
                                     new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = line.Uom, 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.UOM ,                               
                                    }, 
                                    new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = line.Qty.ToString(), 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.ReceiptQty ,
                                        Commit = true
                                    },                                                     
                                      new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = line.Price.ToString(), 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.UnitCost,
                                        Commit = true
                                    },
                                      new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = line.DiscPct.ToString(), 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent,
                                        Commit = true
                                    },
                                     new Value 
                                    {
                                        Value = line.LineRemarks, 
                                        LinkedCommand = ReturnSchema.DocumentDetails.NoteText ,       
                                        Commit = true
                                    }
                                    };
                        Document = Document.Concat(Docline).ToArray();

         //save
                    AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] save = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] {
                                ReturnSchema.Actions.Save,
         ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.Type,
                        ReturnSchema.DocumentSummary.ReceiptNbr
                            };
Document = Document.Concat(save).ToArray();
        //EXCEPTION HERE
         var ReturnDoc = context.PO302000Submit(Document)[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

After i submit the header data, I cleared the Commands. But its strange that it was working before.

```
 context.PO302000Submit(Document);
 Document = new Command[] { };
```